# Update Registry Key (Change starting day of week in Windows ) via Powershell - Simple and easy not fancy like mentioned below

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am updating a reg key via GPO but it fails to update (Still Dont know why, though looking into it). Is there a way to do it via powershell ? I will include this in logon script.

FYI: HKCU\Control Panel\International > iFirstDayOfWeek > 0

Can someone post a script or cmdlt to do so ?

Too complex : "Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx*.mydomain.com Uri | %{set-itemproperty -Path $*.PSPath Uri -Value ( $*.Uri -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" )}"

Answer (score 1):

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\26\SU_1429977.ps1
## get current value
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International'| Select-Object iFirstDayOfWeek

## set new value
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name 'iFirstDayOfWeek' -Value 1

## check if new value is set
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International'| Select-Object iFirstDayOfWeek
```

Sample output

```
iFirstDayOfWeek
---------------
0

iFirstDayOfWeek
---------------
1
```

Comment: Thnx , the one u referred as possible duplicate is too complex. This one is simple and straight

Answer (score 1):

If someone is wondering about the key values:

0: Monday
1:Tuesday
and so on
6: Sunday

So basically you either want '6' or '0' in this value depending on the requirement for calendar on Windows